# SharePoint 2013 Survey repeat unanswered question

Tags: 2013, survey

I have a survey in SharePoint 2013.  Is there a way to make a skipped or unanswered question repeat at the end of all of the survey questions? Has anyone encountered this situation?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to make a skipped or unanswered question repeat at the
>   end of all of the survey questions?

No, not out of the box.

You could just make these questions required. (They are just SharePoint columns displayed as survey questions.)

[image]